# Как с помощью python правильно распарсить xml

Tags: python, xmlparser

Есть такой xml:

```
<price>
<date>2020-12-12 14:52</date>
<firmName>Интернет магазин Lekos</firmName>
<firmId>25106</firmId>
<categories>
...
</categories>
<items>
<item>
<id>52</id>
<categoryId>68</categoryId>
<code>234508</code>
<vendor>Uwatch</vendor>
<stock>В наличии</stock>
<param name="Тип механизма">Кварцевые</param>
<param name="Водостойкость">Базовая</param>
<param name="Тип ремешка">Каучуковый </param>
<param name="Пол">Мужские, Женские</param>
<param name="Подсветка">Электронная</param>
<param name="Тип индикации">Электронные</param>
<param name="Функции">Уведомление о звонках, С пульсометром, С измерением давления, С сенсорным экраном</param>
<param name="Стиль">Спортивные, Умные</param>
<param name="Стекло">Пластиковое </param>
<param name="Пол">Мужские</param>
<param name="Форма корпуса">Круглые</param>
<param name="Страна производитель">Китай</param>
<guarantee type="manufacturer">true</guarantee>
<custom>1</custom>
```

Как правильно распарсить данные, которые находятся в param name?

Comment: попробуйте для начала библиотеку `xmltodict`

Comment: у меня эта библиотека плохо работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему бы не родной библиотекой

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(string)
for items in root.findall('items'):
    for item in items.findall('item'):
        for param in item.findall('param'):
            print(param.attrib['name'])
```

в результате

```
Тип механизма
Водостойкость
Тип ремешка
Пол
Подсветка
...
```

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно!

Comment: Единственное что, мне нужно еще вытащить не только категории param.attrib['name'], но и значения типа "Кварцевые" и тд )

Comment: `print(param.attrib['name'], param.text)`

Comment: Класс. Спасибо!